# Count how many pixels with a specific color in an image?

Tags: image, imagemagick-convert

I want to loop through a folder of images and output to console how many pixels are #333212, how many are #332211 etc. Is this possible in PHP? I found a [package](http://image.intervention.io/) that *manipulates* images but not one that can detect colors of each pixel. Does such a tool or function exist in the PHP library?

EDIT: Doesn't have to be in PHP, the less packages I have to install the better.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php

Comment: I remember having a rough time installing that, going to try again. It doesn't have to be php (check my edit).

Comment: Chances are, ImageMagick is already installed on your computer if you are using some flavor of Unix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with ImageMagick, like this. Say we want to count the red pixels...

```
# First create a little test strip with black, white, red, green and blue parts
convert -size 50x50 xc:black xc:white xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append out.png
```

[image]

Now convert anything non-red to black so that only `red` pixels remain

```
convert out.png -fill black +opaque red n.png
```

[image]

Now count the red pixels by cloning the resulting picture and making the clone fully black (by setting everything to zero), and running a comparison to count how many pixels are not black

```
convert n.png                    \
    \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) \
    -metric AE -compare          \
    -format "%[distortion]" info:
2500
```

And 2500 looks like 50px by 50px to me :-)

**Note**

The `AE` is the Absolute Error, i.e. a simple count of the number of differing pixels. The `-format "%[distortion]" info:` part causes ImageMagick to output the count (`%distortion`) as a number (`info:`) rather than as an image.

Obviously, you replace `red` with `"#333212"` for your problem.

You can also do all that in one visit, like this:

```
convert input.png               \
   -fill black +opaque red      \
   \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \) \
   -metric AE -compare          \
   -format "%[distortion]" info:
```